# NodeJs/ExpressJs - Why use a flash/message middleware

Tags: node.js, express

Why should we use a flash/message middleware like connect-flash? What benefits/values does it brings to a nodejs web application?

Can't we simply send a response object instead of using it?

Does it complement a front-end notification tools like toastr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used express-flash which is used by the server to send flash messages to the rendering engine. If you are using jade as your rendering engine, you can use a partial jade file to detect the presence of these flash messages and show appropriate animations or display. Whereas on the other hand if we are using a front end notification tool we need to implement a listener on the client side to explicitly detect these toasts. I assume connect-flash is similar

Answer (score 3):

"Flash" middleware helps you send information (an object, array, etc.) to a request you are **redirecting** to.

Example: you are displaying a list of users and want to delete a specific user. In your `DELETE /users/123` handler you'd probably want to redirect to `GET /users` to display all remaining users. But probably you also want to display a message "User 123 deleted successfully".

Flash middleware makes it easy to send this message to the **next** request handler.

The alternative would be to:

1. Encode the information into the URL you are redirecting to.
2. Store the information in your session. But this is exactly what flash middleware does, so it's probably easier to use one out of the box instead of implementing it yourself.